# NodeJS TransactionID with Continuation-local-storage

Tags: node.js

Folks, I'd like to implement transaction id tracking in NodeJS.  After reading this article, https://datahero.com/blog/2014/05/22/node-js-preserving-data-across-async-callbacks/, I get the following error from the code:

```
var server = express();
var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace
var namespace = getNamespace('com.me')
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// create a transaction id for each request
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var tid = uuid.v4();

    // wrap the events from request and response
    namespace.bindEmitter(req);
    namespace.bindEmitter(res);

    // run following middleware in the scope of
    // the namespace we created
    namespace.run(function() {

        // set tid on the namespace, makes it
        // available for all continuations
        namespace.set('tid', tid);
        next();
    });
});
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'bindEmitter' of undefined
```

Comment: The only difference I can see in your code and that code is this:

var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace,

    namespace = getNamespace('com.datahero'),

    uuid = require('node-uuid');

might not have anything to do with it but just a quick guess-job.

Comment: also the typo re '' ,... ‘tid’

Answer (score 8):

Folks,
  Here is the proper code that works:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
var namespace = cls.createNamespace('com.me');

var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// create a transaction id for each request
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var namespace = cls.getNamespace('com.me');
    var tid = uuid.v4();

    // wrap the events from request and response
    namespace.bindEmitter(req);
    namespace.bindEmitter(res);

    // run following middleware in the scope of
    // the namespace we created
    namespace.run(function() {

        // set tid on the namespace, makes it
        // available for all continuations
        namespace.set('tid', tid);
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's probably useful to point out the most important change.  
  
In the initial example, you called `getNamespace(foo)` without first having called `createNamespace(foo)`.  As the namespace was never defined, calling `getNamespace('com.me')` returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

First we need to create namespace, then try to access the same.

```
var ns = cls.createNamespace('com.me');
```

then inside any method probably a middleware, access it like

```
ns = cls.getNamespace('com.me');
```

in case if you are in the same context of creating the namespace then you can play around with variable 'ns' itself.

Though it's a way too old post, hope it would be helpful for someone ;)

Good day!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting here because they are running into issues using continuation-local-storage with async functions also try this fork of the library that integrates with Node's new async_hooks API.

[cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked)

Comment: Very helpful, I was having trouble finding a more recent library using Google, your comment led me to cls-hooked.

Comment: i also thought so, but async_hooks are still in experimental state, so is there any other way ?